# How to Make Video Streaming Website

Tags: javascript, video, web

What kind of technologies i have to learn to make video streaming website.
I want to make my own video player on my website. Like youtube or vimeo or google or facebook has their own player.
I want to make live streaming with that video.
Can anybody tell me what must i to learn?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure your question is a bit confusing for people! Do you just want to embed a youtube/vimeo video on your site?

If that's the case, they have code snippets for you to use.

Do you want to "make your own youtube"? If that's the case, there's a lot to learn! And video streaming bandwidth can be expensive (expect a few thousand dollars a month and up and if you have even moderate traffic).

What you'd likely need is a content server to host the videos. You could use amazon (we had issues with their buffering) or something like edgecast (great service, but you'll pay more!). These will sit on a server like "cdn.yourdomain.com/videos".

Then you can begin by using the HTML5  tag to point at it! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video

You'll have it up and running in a Saturday but i'll be slow and ugly.... From there, there are infinite front-end UI possibilities.

(source: I co-developed an online streaming video platform, now defunct: http://www.wired.com/2012/05/interactive-dirty-work-fourth-wall/)